# Eset Endpoint blocking CherryPy web service?

Tags: macos, python, webserver, eset

I'm not positive I'm asking this in the right place, so if you think it should be elsewhere, please be gentle and tell me where you think I should ask.

I have a web service written in Python, using CherryPy.  It worked fine until I installed Eset Endpoint Antivirus.  I've tried turning off web protection and making sure the ports were open, as well as changing the port, but no matter what I do, when I try to run my application, I get an error that the port is unavailable.  Has anyone encountered this, and if so, what is the fix?

I'm on a Mac, in case that has any bearing.  I uninstalled Eset and everything works correctly, so I am positive that Eset is causing the problem.